# .gitconfig system location confusion

Tags: git

On windows 10 when I run:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

I get:

```
    file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=input
    file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
    file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
    file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
    ...
    file:"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    file:"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   http.sslbackend=openssl
    file:"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"   diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
    ....
    file:C:/Users/user/.gitconfig  alias.st=status
    file:C:/Users/user/.gitconfig  alias.co=checkout
```

Why do I have both:

```
file:"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"
```

and:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"
```

Should I not only have ONE system location?

And in Eclipse it defaults to the one in %APPDATA%

[image]

So I assume it/eclipse will never consider the file in:

"C:\ProgramData/Git/config"

?

Comment: Use `git config --help` and go to `FILES` section. [Documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/master@%7B2018-01-07%7D/Documentation/git-config.txt#L231)

Comment: Ok still a bit confusing with two "system" locations on windows. I have updated the post to include the paths selected (cannot be changed) by eclipse and it seems it will never read the options from C:\ProgramData\Git\config so those need to be copied to the config in %APPDATA%

Comment: If you use `--system` flag for `git`, then it will read only `%Git%\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"`. I do not know if Eclipse read `C:\ProgramData/Git/config` or not, but it should be easy check for yourself.

Comment: My point was that eclipse is hardcoded to only read the gitconfig file from %APPDATA% - see above screenshot - and that you cannot change that. Seems quite odd.

Answer (score 1):

There are --system config values, which you can see if you run:

> git config --list --system

and there are --global config values, which you can see if you run:

> git config --list --global

so when you run:

> git config --list --show-origin

You can see both lists mixed.

And if you'll run it from within a local repository, you'll see it mixed also with the local config values, those that you can get if you'll run:

> git config --list --local

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer is given in the link provided by @PetSerAl in the comment to the question. The explanation is that there are multiple different git implementations available for Windows and by splitting the system configuration into two locations you can have one system config that can be shared between implementations and one that is specific to the current implementation.

My interpretation of the doc is that the one in `C:\\ProgramData/Git/config` is the shared one and the one in `C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig` is specific to the git implementation you are using.

It looks like Eclipse is not aware of this Windows-specific thing with two system settings files. Git for Windows is however aware of the other shared file and should make use of it when invoked from Eclipse.